# Trying to test creating a Scala Plugin with version 2.13, getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError sclaa Serializable

Tags: scala, plugins

running into this error when trying to follow an SBT Plugin tutorial

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable
[error] sbt.std.InputWrapper$.valueMacroImpl(InputWrapper.scala:136)
[error] java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error] java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error] java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error] java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[error] scala.reflect.macros.runtime.JavaReflectionRuntimes$JavaReflectionResolvers.$anonfun$resolveJavaReflectionRuntime$6(JavaReflectionRuntimes.scala:51)
```

Worthy note: I'm trying to use a later version of scala, ver "2.13.11", the publisher is using "2.10.4".

What am I missing or what's 2.13 Scala missing that could cause this? What's the solution?

Comment: The video you linked to is 22 minutes long. You can make the life easier to people who can help you (and increase the chances to get a meaningful answer) by sharing the bits of your build that are producing the error.

Comment: **sbt** itself is written in `2.12` and thus, plugins must be written using `2.12` as well.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you mean if I switch to ver 2.12 instead of 2.13 this would work?

Comment: @stefanobaghino don't need to watch the video, that was just for context, I'll remove it.

Comment: @user2167582 yes, I would expect that will be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez said, the problem is the scala version that you are using.

There is an issue already closed about [Cannot compile SBT plugin under Scala 2.13.0](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5032). Where the maintainer of the repo says

> sbt plugin should be created like this:
>
> ```scala
> lazy val root = (project in file("."))
>   .enablePlugins(SbtPlugin)  
>   .settings(
>     name := "sbt-something"
>   )
> ```
>
> and Scala version should not be specified unless you're cross building between sbt 1.x and 0.13.
> There's no sbt available under 2.13.0, so expectation doesn't make sense.

Also it's explained in the docs [Sbt - Creating an auto plugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html#Creating+an+auto+plugin)

> - **sbt plugins** must be **compiled** with **Scala 2.12.x** that sbt itself is compiled in. By **NOT specifying scalaVersion**, sbt will default to the Scala version suited for a plugin.

One of the users that commented in the sbt issue mentioned above, created an [sbt 1.x hello world](https://github.com/logc/sbt-hello) where you can see used as the *homepage* of the example showed in [Creating an auto plugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html#Creating+an+auto+plugin)

```scala
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"
ThisBuild / homepage := Some(url("https://github.com/sbt/sbt-hello"))

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(SbtPlugin)
  .settings(
    name := "sbt-hello",
    pluginCrossBuild / sbtVersion := {
      scalaBinaryVersion.value match {
        case "2.12" => "1.2.8" // set minimum sbt version
      }
    }
  )
```